# Sort and display specific values from stored array

Tags: java, arrays

For my assignment, I am supposed to make a program that will help decide baseball players to draft. The program prompts a scout to enter info about the player, and store it in an array. It will then check the array and display a list of players under 25 years old AND have a batting average of .280 or over. The list must be sorted by age.

Oh and the menu IS required.

My problem is that it's not giving me any output besides the title! Is it not sorting? Is the if-statement not working? WHAT'S WRONG!?

The *players* class looks like this:

```
public class players 
{
    String name;
    String position;
    int age;
    double average;
}
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class BlueJays 
{    
    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
    static players[] arr;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    String quit = "n";
    while("n".equals(quit))
    {
        //display menu
        System.out.println("Toronto Blue Jays Drafting Program - Main Menu");
        System.out.println("1) Input Blue Jays data");
        System.out.println("2) Display possible draft choices");      
        System.out.println("3) Quit program");
        System.out.print("Please choose an option by inputting the number of your choice: ");
        String choiceString = br.readLine();
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(choiceString);

        if(choice == 1)
        {
            inputInfo();
        }else if(choice == 2)
        {
            sortInfo();
        }else if(choice == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Are you sure you want to quit? (y/n) ");  
            quit = br.readLine();
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Not a valid option.");
        }                  
    }
}

//method to input names of Blue Jays
public static void inputInfo() throws IOException
{  
    players temp = new players();
    System.out.print("How many players would you like to enter? ");
    int x = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine()).intValue();
    arr = new players[x];     

    //loop through players
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {

        System.out.println("Enter player information.");

        System.out.println("Input first and last name: ");
        String name = br.readLine();
        temp.name = name;       

        System.out.println("Input position: ");
        String position = br.readLine();
        temp.position = position;

        System.out.println("Input batting average (e.g. .246): ");
        String averageString = br.readLine();
        temp.average = Double.parseDouble(averageString);

        System.out.println("Input age: ");
        temp.age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println(" ");

        // Copy the software name and quantity to the global variables
        arr[i] = temp;
    }   
}

//method to sort and display info
public static void sortInfo()
{              
    //sort by quantity
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i].age > arr[j].age)
            {
                players  temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }

    }            
    System.out.println("Draft Choices 2013");        
    //output
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i].age <= 25 && arr[i].average >= 0.280)
        {
            System.out.println("Name: " + arr[i].name);    
            System.out.println("Age: " + arr[i].age);
            System.out.println("Position: " + arr[i].position);
            System.out.println("Batting average: " + arr[i].average);
            System.out.println("   ");        
        }            

    }
    }
}
```

I need to hand this is very soon so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "only the title"? Only the `Toronto Blue Jays Drafting Program - Main Menu` line? That would be quite strange.

Comment: @SJuan76 No, I meant the "Draft Choices 2013" line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WTF from the code that might be causing you issues:

```
players temp = new players();
System.out.print("How many players would you like to enter? ");
int x = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine()).intValue();
arr = new players[x];     

//loop through players
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{

    System.out.println("Enter player information.");

    System.out.println("Input first and last name: ");
    String name = br.readLine();
    temp.name = name;       
     ....
```

}

You create only a `players` instance and reuse it. So, you do not have an array of (say) 20 different `players`, but an array that points 20 times to the same object (*instance*). That instance data will be continuosly overwritten and only hold the data of the last player you put in, and if it has `age > 25` no records will be printed due to your filter.

Move the instance creation inside the `for`

```
System.out.print("How many players would you like to enter? ");
int x = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine()).intValue();
arr = new players[x];     

//loop through players
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    players temp = new players();  // <---- THIS

    System.out.println("Enter player information.");

    System.out.println("Input first and last name: ");
    String name = br.readLine();
    temp.name = name;       
     ....
```

}